# MS Access VBA web scraper return "&amp;" inplace of "&"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the Access VBA to do some web scraping.

It works fine for scraping table columns in most places but I have found that when there is a string such as

`Mon&day` it actually returns `Mon&amp;day`.

I am using the IE object to do the web scraping

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

And for scraping individual cells I am doing:

```
tdRow(subCounter).innerHTML
```

I know that the `&` is a special character in HTML, which is probably why this is happening. Is there a way to return the HTML as it is instead of letting VBA do some further parsing?

Comment: Instead of `innerHTML` try `innerText`

Comment: Just because you dont already know (given by your post) thats how you escape ampersands in HTML. You could use Santosh's response or you could learn how to escape html characters. I think its worth knowing about but not necessarily the best approach to escape them here. You should look up which ones need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **innerText** to get just the text, without spacing and inner element tags.